# Merge tag [execution-api] into [google-apps-script-api]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

**Proposal**

It is proposed to merge the [execution-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-api) with [google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) and make the former a synonym of the latter. If there is anyone who can vote, the synonym [is already voted upon](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script-api/synonyms).

**Reasoning**

1. Both [execution-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-api) and [google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) represent
   the same service: [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/)
2. Execution API is the [former name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/samples/execute) of the Apps Script API ([google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) wiki references that)

**Tag stats**

- The [google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) has a [good short wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script-api/info) and a
  [nearly a hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) questions (96 ATTOW)
- The [execution-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-api) has a [rudimentary wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/execution-api/info) and less than [two dosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-api?sort=newest) (16 ATTOW) questions

**Tag graphs**

Here is a [google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) activity graph [during its lifetime](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1261578#graph) (only neutral or positive non-deleted questions):

[image: google-apps-script-api-5-year-graph]

While the [execution-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-api) activity basically flatlined (last question with half a year gap last year and none this year):

[image: execution-api-5-year-graph]

---

Note: a moderator intervention is would likely speed things up as we do not currently have enough 5-score answerers in the primary tag to complete the voting successfully (1 suggested + 1 voted, 2 more to go, still one short).